# Mermaid major mode not showing up after installation

Tags: major-mode, doom

I've installed `mermaid-mode` by using `package-install` and MPLA but for some reason, it's not showing up when I type it after  `M-x`. (I get `Match required`). I'm running Doom Emacs. Any clue why this might be happening?

Comment: To be a useful question you would need to say explicitly exactly what you did, what you saw, and what you expected to see instead, at each step.

Comment: @Drew I see that now. I ended up just learning to use PlantUML instead. Thanks for the help!